# Pass only checkboxes checked for other view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, rails-4-2-1

I have two views, the first is a table that show all authorizations, how I make for pass only the authorizations checked for other view?

This is first view: (all ok here)

```
(...)
 <% @authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag 'authorization_marked' %></td>
(...)
<%= f.button :submit, "To Reserve" %>
```

My first and second controller:

```
def index
    if params[:search_employee_by_cpf].present?
      @employees = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf]).all
      @authorizations = Authorization.search_employee_by_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf]).all
    else
      @authorizations = []
    end
  end

  # GET /refinancings/new
  def new
    @employee = Employee.search_cpf(params[:search_employee_by_cpf])
    @authorizations.authorization_marked = true # PROBLEM HERE
    @refinancing = Refinancing.new
  end
```

In other view I want show just the checked:

```
  <h3>Reserved value</h3>
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>Contract number</th>
      <th>Parcel value X Quantity of Parcels</th>
    </thead>
    <% @authorizations.each do |authorization| %>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><%= authorization.contract_number %></td>
          <td><%= number_to_currency authorization.parcel_value %> x <%= authorization.qtd_parcel %></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

Comment: This part: `how I make for pass only the authorizations checked for other view?`, I did not understand at all.

Comment: More context is needed. Can you show the whole form section for the first view? And also the controller action rendering the HTML in your third block of code?

Comment: @AnthonyE - is my repository: https://github.com/eltonsantos/playing_checkboxes

Comment: @MatthewCliatt - https://github.com/eltonsantos/playing_checkboxes

Comment: I have four authorizations, I check just two, click in submit. In other view I will show just this two authorizations checked, just this that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! It is My solution, created a repository for this, take a look on code:

https://github.com/eltonsantos/playing_checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

So your first form needs to capture the id numbers of all the rows you want to pass to the second view. In your second action, you need to capture those parameters, and make a collection of the objects you want the second view to load.

Take a very close look at what data is being passed when you post the first form, that's the data you have to use to create the next collection you want.

Comment: Have some example on git ot in another place? I 'm trying, but nothing yet, I make a example on my git:  github.com/eltonsantos/playing_checkboxes

Comment: <%= check_box_tag 'authorization_ids[]', authorization.id %> this is my checkbox, it's ok?